# hctreemap to hctreemap2 --> Could not find function "hctreemap2"

Tags: r

I have tried to reproduce the one mentioned in the link  https://rpubs.com/jbkunst/hctreemap2. But getting error message as 
*"Error in hctreemap2(data = GNI2014, group_vars = "continent", size_var = "population") :    could not find function "hctreemap2"*. Also verified the dependencies but not sure what is missing. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of `highcharter`, version `0.5.0`, was published `2017-01-17 08:36:29`,  as you can see from the documentation. `hctreemap2` was proposed since then and is in development. It is not in `highcharter` as it is released on CRAN.  You could theoretically pull the code from [github](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/blob/master/dev/treemap5.R)  if you wanted, it's in the `dev` repo under `treemap5.R`, and looks to be something they'll include in the 0.6.0 release.